# mysqli_query DELETE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a PHP application and I would like to delete a line in my database.

This is my code :

```
$_SESSION['bdd'] = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
mysqli_query($_SESSION['bdd'], "SELECT * FROM practices");
mysqli_query($_SESSION['bdd'], "DELETE FROM 'practices' WHERE 'id' = '".$idPractice."'");
mysqli_close($_SESSION['bdd']);
```

I tried with this too :

```
$_SESSION['bdd'] = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
mysqli_query($_SESSION['bdd'], "SELECT * FROM practices");
mysqli_query($_SESSION['bdd'], "DELETE FROM 'practices' WHERE 'id' = $idPractice");
mysqli_close($_SESSION['bdd']);
```

But still not working, $idPractice is an int and works perfectly and I do a var_dump
This has to be very simple but I don't know where there is a mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use backticks. `'practices'` and here `'id'`. Quotes are for strings. Also not your issue but why run the `select`?

Comment: Thanks :) for the select, it's an error of copy/paste :)